# How do I check what MSA I'm logged in with when developing a Cortana skill?

Tags: c#, cortana

I'm developing a Cortana skill. When I gave utterance to enable my bot "**Ask Snipper to**", Cortana invoked the skill. But when I utter the same utterance in other's systems/laptops it results in a Bing search because I'm logged in to a different MSA.  How do I discover what account is invoking the skill?  How can I change it?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Check how you've published the skill. If you are developing a skill, it will only be available to your MSA. On the other laptops, you likely aren't logged in to your MSA so the invocation phrase isn't getting recognized. This [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana-winpc/how-to-log-out-of-cortana) has an example of how to check your logged in account and how to log out of Cortana.  (You can use the same mechanism to re-log in.) The next publishing steps are publishing to a group (so only select MSAs can invoke the skill; you can add other people's MSAs to a group to QA a skill and only the group will see it), and then to world (after certification, that means anyone can invoke your skill.)  You can get more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/publish-skill)